# How to send data from Spring Boot to React front-end without the use of a Controller?

Tags: java, spring-boot

If I have an endpoint, that when hit calls a function that has a `CompleteabeFuture.runAsync()` call, how can I send this data back to the front end.
Here is an example of `async`function similar to mine (just simpler):

```java
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
    int count = 0;
    if(test.getNumberComplete() > count){
        count = test.getNumberComplete();
        logger.info("{}/{} complete so far", count, test.getNumberComplete());
    }
}
```

Basically, this is running in the background after the Controller has already returned `ResponseEntity`. So my question is, how can I return the data that is being logged in `logger.info()` to my front-end. Is this possible at all since the Controller has already returned? My end goal is to show these results in the top corner of the website's screen, something like "1/3 complete so far".

Comment: I would skip the async part in the backend, and use async mechanisms in the frontend instead. Then the frontend can go on to do other things while waiting for a response, and show the data when it is ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use websockets. There's a simple example [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/) that uses STOMP to pass messages back and forth.